# Why does the radius of convergence stay the same when adding two power series with the same radius of convergence?

Tags: complex-analysis

If we build the sum of two power series , $\sum a_kz^k$, $\sum b_kz^k$ both with radius of convergence 1,  why does the resulting power series: $$\sum (a_k+b_k)z^k$$ also have RoC 1?

Is it because : $$|\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}| = 1 , |\frac{b_k}{b_{k+1}}|=1$$

$$|\frac{a_k+b_k}{a_{k+1}+b_{k+1}}|$$

that doesnt really do anything T_T .... If you see how to show this, please do tell.

Comment: Not true. The series has radius of convergence *at least* 1, but it may very well be larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The radius of convergence need not stay the same.

Let $p(z)$ have radius of convergence $1$, and let $q(z)$ have radius of convergence $4$. Then $(q+p)(z)$ and $(q-p)(z)$ have radius of convergence $1$, but their sum has radius of convergence $4$.

For any $k\ge 1$, including "$k=\infty$", we can find power series with radius of convergence $1$ whose sum has radius of convergence $k$.

Comment: I dont see, why cant the sum be smaller than one? And how would you create one with k= infinity if both are required to have the same radius of convergence (by setting $b_k = -a_k$ ? )

Comment: @bakabakabaka: Sure, $b_k=-a_k$ is good. For for a fancier example, $e^z-\frac{1}{1-z}$ and $e^z+\frac{1}{1-z}$. As for your question about why not less than $1$, the sum has radius of convergence $\ge 1$ by say the ratio test.

Comment: How does one find the radius of convergence of the sum ? F.e. how did you know that q+p had radius of convergence 1 ? 1+4 would be 5, no? Same with q-p , too, it would be 3 ?

Comment: @bakabakabaka: Formally, use Ratio Test or Root Test. More informally, if $p(z)$ is nice only when $|z|\lt 1$, and $q(z)$ is nice for $|z|\lt 4$, then $q(z)+p(z)$ is nice only when $|z|\lt 1$. To put it another way, $p(z)$ has a singularity somewhere on the circle $|z|=1$, and $q(z)$ is OK for any $z$ with $|z|\lt 4$, so $q(z)+p(z)$ goes bad somewhere on $|z|=1$.

Comment: How do you use the ratio test in this case? Which is $\lim |\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}|$ ? If you only know the radius of convergence but not the functions p(z) , q(z).  I dont understand how to extend your informal argument of $q+p$ for example $q-p$ .

Comment: @bakabakabaka: Informal argument for $q-p$ is the same. For formal, Ratio Test on coefficients is unwieldy, so here is another way. Let $\sum p_n z^n$ have radius of convergence $1$, let $\sum q_n z^n$ have radius of convergence $4$. So for example $\sum p_n z^n$ diverges if $|z|=1.01$. But $\sum q_n z^n$ converges for $|z|=1.01$. It follows that $\sum (p_n+q_n)z^n$ diverges for $|z|=1.01$. So radius of convergence of sum is $\le 1.01$. In same way, it is $\le 1+\epsilon$ for every positive $\epsilon$, so it is $\le 1$.

Comment: Thanks. +++++++